# @font-face, Firefox, CDN, document.domain

Tags: javascript, firefox, fonts, font-face, cdn

Is it possible to get a custom font to display properly across all browsers without being able to modify the access headers to my CDN? Would integrating some javascript script like this: `document.domain='domain.com';` work?

Thanks!

Comment: You can only set `document.domain` to your own less-specific domain (like, you can change "shop.whatever.com" to "whatever.com"). Seems to me that a CDN that won't let you control important headers is kind-of broken.

Answer (score 0):

The spec requires that cross-site font loads be protected by CORS, so you need to get your CDN sending the right CORS headers.